# RazorEngine output HTML

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

I have a little piece of code, which gets data from a DB, and I want to parse it into a .cshtml Razor-View-Template. therefor i create a variable of a new TemplateService and execute .parse() on that. Now I want to output the file to the user. What is the best performing function to accomplish this task? I have an MVC application. And as the text above already describes, this is a little template system.

**Edit:**

For example:

- I have a folder templates/default-tpl/, which contains a file index.cshtml
- This file contains some Razor-related variables (for example @ViewData["Title"]
- Now i have a Controller, which calls the RazorEngine TemplateService's Parse() function with the corresponding ViewData.
- Now I have the HTML ready and parsed

So the question is, from this point, how do i output the website the most performant way? Or is there even a complete different approach possible?

Comment: Can you post some code showing what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sadly, not yet, but I will update the post above to make it a bit clearer

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel? Isn't that done by default by any default ASPNET MVC project?

Comment: Well, looks like, i have thought a bit too difficult. Thanks for bringing me back to the roots, @AdrianSalazar